# How to Loop through Values in Google Sheet while creating a Trigger?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have Google Apps Script Code in the following format:

```
var key = "ID of the Sheet";

var key1 = "ID of the Sheet";

function createTriggers() {

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('filter')
      .forSpreadsheet(key)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}

function createTriggers() {

  ScriptApp.newTrigger('filter')
      .forSpreadsheet(key1)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
}
```

How to loop through all keys (key, key1, key2...) and create triggers via a single function?

Comment: Pretty broad question. Can you be more specific? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to create a trigger for multiple sheets in a standalone script, as of now, I have to create a separate function for each trigger as seen in the above example. Need a way to loop through keys and create triggers via a single function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
function createTriggers() {
    var keys = [
        'key1',
        'key2'
    ]
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        ScriptApp.newTrigger('filter')
            .forSpreadsheet(keys[i])
            .onEdit()
            .create();
    }
}
```

[Information about for loops](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp)